# Is there a way to test the presence of an element on a page with selenium?

Tags: python, html, selenium-webdriver

I’m making a program using Selenium with Python and I have a problem.

At some point in the test, according to a parameter that I can't know, a button must appear on the page or no.

In the HTML, here is its tag:

```
<button class="_1H_R6 _1ZefG _29cJe" data-test="player-toggle-keyboard">content</button>
```

To adapt, I want to run a piece of code only if this button is present on the webpage.

Is that possible?

If I were sure the button was on the page, I would put it in a variable as follows:

```
element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//button[@data-test="player-toggle-keyboard"]')
```

But it puts an error if the button is not detected:

```
  File "/home/prog/Documents/duolingo-bot/main.py", line 18, in <module>
    element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//button[@data-test="player-toggle-keyboard"]')
  File "/home/prog/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 738, in find_element
    return self.execute(Command.FIND_ELEMENT, {"using": by, "value": value})["value"]
  File "/home/prog/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 344, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/home/prog/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 229, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//button[@data-test="player-toggle-keyboard"]"}
  (Session info: chrome=115.0.5790.170); For documentation on this error, please visit: https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/troubleshooting/errors#no-such-element-exception
Stacktrace:
#0 0x55d0c8b32c43 <unknown>
#1 0x55d0c886f3f7 <unknown>
#2 0x55d0c88acf6b <unknown>
#3 0x55d0c88ad061 <unknown>
#4 0x55d0c88e7a44 <unknown>
#5 0x55d0c88cd5bd <unknown>
#6 0x55d0c88e563c <unknown>
#7 0x55d0c88cd363 <unknown>
#8 0x55d0c88a17c2 <unknown>
#9 0x55d0c88a256e <unknown>
#10 0x55d0c8af822d <unknown>
#11 0x55d0c8afcf83 <unknown>
#12 0x55d0c8b06388 <unknown>
#13 0x55d0c8afd9aa <unknown>
#14 0x55d0c8acde5e <unknown>
#15 0x55d0c8b1e538 <unknown>
#16 0x55d0c8b1e6df <unknown>
#17 0x55d0c8b2cf09 <unknown>
#18 0x7ff2ca1ff609 start_thread
```

I thought something like that:

```
if test_to_see_if_the_button_is_there():
    // code1

else:
    // code2
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Either catch the exception, or use find_elements(...) and check that at least one element is returned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write a method like this

```py
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException        

def check_exists_by_xpath(xpath):
    try:
        webdriver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath)
    except NoSuchElementException:
        return False
    return True
```